# In wordpress project in css file set path to image

Tags: css, wordpress

In  WP 4.2 project in css file I write like:

```
background-image: url('/wp-content/plugins/artistssongs/images/fancybox_sprite.png');
```

But I dislike the way to show full path to image which is inside plugin and I can not use php/wp constants like WP_PLUGIN_URL
which can be decision for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this and you css path for plugin will be:
pluginname/style.css
and path for images folder in plugin is:
pluginname/images

```
background-image: url('/images/fancybox_sprite.png');
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not clear. I prefer to keep my images in pluging's subdirectory, but not in common /images/ directory, as you wrote..

Comment: @MastadmMsotdum you are welcome. if its correct then can you please mark correct ans